# C#/WinForms: Set CheckedListBox items that contains data from a string/array

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox, contains, checkedlistbox

Is there a way to determine if my checkedlistbox's items contain data coming from a string/array?

My textbox contains the following:

```
txtActivities.Text = "ABC, DEF";
```

My checklistbox (contains the following)

- ABC
- DEF
- GHI
- JKL

What I want to do is:
(1) Split the 'activities' into array:

```
string[] tokens = txtActivities.ToString().Split(',');
```

and (2) try to 'check' the items found in my checkedboxlist (cListActivities) based on my textbox

`for (int i = 0; i < frm.clistActivities.Items.Count; i++){`

```
if (frm.clistActivities.Items[i].ToString().Contains(tokens)) //error?
    {
    frm.clistActivities.SetItemChecked(i); // not working
    }}
```

The output: Item ABC and DEF should be checked.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check whether the tokens contain the item, then SetItemChecked to `true`.

In other words,

```
if (Array.IndexOf(tokens, frm.clistActivities.Items[i].ToString() >= 0)
     frm.clistActivities.SetItemChecked(i, true);
```

Comment: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Contains'

Answer (score 1):

You have a space between the comma and D.

Try this:

```
"ABC,DEF"
```

Edit: This code worked for me.

```
  foreach(string strMyString in tokens)
            {   
             this.clistActivites.SetItemChecked(clistActivities.FindStringExact(strMyString), true);
            }
```